# React.js - ReactDOM.render or can you use inline?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started development in REACT and have some small queries on how to use it inline.

I have for example the following code snippet.

```js
    ReactDOM.render(
      <RitualPromoCode url="/Home/ValidatePromoCode" code="Bongo" location="1" package="17" />,
      document.getElementById('promo-code')
    );
```

however when using the above using it within my MVC page is annoying...i would like to be able to within the HTML page use the new "tag" inline...e.g.

```html
      <RitualPromoCode url="/Home/ValidatePromoCode" code="Bongo" location="1" package="17" />
```

How do i go about doing this?

On another note..I want to use multiple components in different parts of my page but don't want to write one HUGE component to use them all together.  How can i get one component to update / modify the properties of another on the same page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call render in one place. Just create some "main" component which will contain all others.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('promo-code')
);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <RitualPromoCode url="/Home/ValidatePromoCode" code="Bongo" location="1" package="17" />
        <SomeOtherComponent />
        <MoreComponent />
        <MyComponent />
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```